# Oracle: why parallel delete doesn't go parallel?

Tags: sql, oracle, parallel-processing, dml

I've tried the following statement. But it doesn't proceed parallel. Why?
How can I speed up the operation?

```
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;

DELETE /*+ parallel(20) */
      FROM  table
      WHERE flag != 'N';
```

[image]

Comment: #1I've found this article http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689 #2Can I disable ROLLBACK?

Comment: There's some advice on using hints with parallel delete at https://community.oracle.com/message/10371302#10371302, but it didn't help me either.

Comment: `DELETE` parallel will only work if the table **is partitioned** and if there are multiple partitions involved in the operation i.e. the `DELETE` must be deleting from multiple partitions instead just a single partition. For non partitioned table you will have to set the table to `PARALLEL` using `ALTER TABLE` and then use  `ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML` with parallel hint in the `DELETE`

Comment: @Annjawn seems a very detailed description. Where in the documentation can we find this?

Comment: @vegatripy http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/usingpe.htm see the section called "Rules for UPDATE, MERGE, and DELETE" second line "Update, merge, and delete parallelism are not possible within a partition, nor on a nonpartitioned table."

Comment: Another reason for `PARALLEL` hint not working is the presence of triggers in the table. A `PARALLEL` hint will almost certainly not work if there are triggers on the tabled which are enabled, so disabling triggers is necessary. But if disabling the trigger breaks the functionality then I guess it's a moot point.

Comment: @Annjawn The partition limitation does not apply anymore, at least since 11g.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;
DELETE /*+ parallel(table, 20) */
  FROM  table
  WHERE flag!= 'N';
```

you can also try another option to delete data, using CTAS, reference from asktom [Deleting many rows from a big table](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689)

> create table new_table unrecoverable as select * from old_table where ....;
>
> drop table old_table;
>
> rename new_table to old_table;
>
> create index old_table_idx1 on old_table(c1,c2) unrecoverable parallel 5;

Comment: #1Doesn't work. I've put an image. The block change happen just by one thread and the operation is thousand times slower than a select.
#2I cannot drop the original table..

Comment: Is your table using bitmap index?

Comment: Or you can just try to Manual Parallelism with different key value ranges or rowid ranges.

Comment: No, don't use bitmap index. I fear the problem is the table is not partitioned. So it create redo segments (unuseful for me), it updates indexes, ecc... all unuseful... can I disable?